# parseInt is not giving actual value and giving always as 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have `input` type which is span. And I want to calculate between two text. So I tried implementing like below. But the alert is always coming `0`

```js
function ValidateFormFTTX(ApproveRejectSave) {

  var acceptedUG = parseInt($('#FEUGLEG_txtReadOnlyAccepted').text());
  var TotalUG = parseInt($('#FEUGLEG_txtReadOnly').text());
  var offerUG = parseInt($('#FEUGLEG_txt').val());

  alert(offerUG);

  var calculatedUG = (parseFloat(TotalUG) + parseFloat(offerUG).toFixed(4));

}
```

```html
<td class="tdWidth disableField">
  <span id="FEUGLEG_txtReadOnly" class="text-center"></span>
</td>

<td class="tdWidth disableField">
  <span id="FEUGLEG_txtReadOnlyAccepted" class="text-center"></span>
</td>


<td class="tdWidth"><input id="FEUGLEG_txt" type="text" class="text-center" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, this);" maxlength="6" /></td>
```

Comment: you need to add an event listener to get the updated value of your input, as it stores the initialized value into the variable so it keep appears because it doesn't track the change,

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman:any link to help ?

Comment: Your snippet seems incorrect. Can you please elaborate on your requirment?It is unclear as to what you need

Comment: as long as you're using jQuery, you can check the [change event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) from jQuery docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not executing ValidateFormFTTX, only the function `isNumberKey` which  you did not provide.

I recommend to not use inline event handlers.

Also you have the toFixed in the wrong place

Alternatively use `type="number"` on the field

Here is working code

```js
function ValidateFormFTTX(event) {

  let acceptedUG = $('#FEUGLEG_txtReadOnlyAccepted').text();
  let TotalUG = $('#FEUGLEG_txtReadOnly').text();
  let offerUG = $('#FEUGLEG_txt').val();

  alert(offerUG);

  var calculatedUG = (parseFloat(TotalUG) + parseFloat(offerUG)).toFixed(4); // the toFixed needs to be after the sum

  if (offerUG === 0) {
    alert('Please enter an offer')
    event.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    return;
  }
  // do whatever 
  alert(calculatedUG);
}

$(function() { // on page load
  $("#approvalForm").on("submit", ValidateFormFTTX);
  $('#FEUGLEG_txt').on("input", function() {
    // Replace any non-digit character with an empty string
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="approvalForm">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdWidth disableField">
          <span id="FEUGLEG_txtReadOnly" class="text-center">10</span>
        </td>

        <td class="tdWidth disableField">
          <span id="FEUGLEG_txtReadOnlyAccepted" class="text-center">20</span>
        </td>


        <td class="tdWidth"><input id="FEUGLEG_txt" type="text" class="text-center" value="0" maxlength="6" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a number field instead of a text field. Also, you never called your `ValidateFormFTTX` function.

**Note:** I added a jQuery debounce plugin to limit the number of times the validation is called upon input.

```js
$('#FEUGLEG_txt').on('input', $.debounce(250, (e) => {
  ValidateFormFTTX(null);
}));

function ValidateFormFTTX(ApproveRejectSave) {
  // Unused
  const acceptedUG = parseFloat($('#FEUGLEG_txtReadOnlyAccepted').text());
  
  const totalUG = parseFloat($('#FEUGLEG_txtReadOnly').text());
  const offerUG = $('#FEUGLEG_txt').get(0).valueAsNumber;

  const calculatedUG = (totalUG + offerUG).toFixed(4);
  
  console.log(calculatedUG);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdWidth disableField">
        <span id="FEUGLEG_txtReadOnly" class="text-center">100</span>
      </td>
      <td class="tdWidth disableField">
        <span id="FEUGLEG_txtReadOnlyAccepted" class="text-center">5</span>
      </td>
      <td class="tdWidth">
        <input id="FEUGLEG_txt" type="number" class="text-center" value="0" max="999999" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that this script is executed after the DOM has fully loaded. You can wrap your code inside a document ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code`enter code here`
});
```

Comment: I want this on button click..